# Google crawling/indexing PHP files

Tags: google-search-console, crawl-errors

All of a sudden I had about 819 errors pop up in my Webmaster Tools accounts, all of which are PHP files. Google has never indexed these before, because they aren't URLs. The main folder they are indexing happens to be the my `/content/` folder which contains basically the relevant information of my site.

My question is: if I block these directories via *robots.txt* will it affect Google crawling my real pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they won't, unless you have relevant pages under `/content`, you'll have no problem with Google crawling you current pages.

Add the entry `Disallow: /content/` to robots.txt.

Google tries to crawl *subdirectories* from your URLs, i.e. if Google finds an internal or external link pointing to a page in your site at /content/foo/foo.html, it will try to crawl `/content/foo` and `/content`.

Comment: Thanks for the help Pascual, to clarify, i don't have pages in this directory, only the files which dynamically generate the pages. By blocking these files, will it then block the pages these files create?

Comment: Of course, when I mean pages I also mean php files, as they generate HTML and thus a page to Google. Blocking that subdirectory, you will block Google from indexing all the pages generated by the files under `/content` :D

Comment: Ok, so adding this to robots.txt would be a terrible idea in my situation, being as my site is being generated from this subdirectory. I need to determine why these are all of a sudden being shown to the world, in order to address the root problem. Thanks!

Comment: No, I confused you, I explained myself wrong: Say your site is `www.example.com`, if your URLs look like `www.example.com/content/...`, **you have a problem**. But if your URLs don't look like `www.example.com/content/...`, but your php files are located in `.../foo/bar/content/` directory **then you are ok**. Google cannot *see* your php files, just the URLs you generate with them.

Comment: My URL's do not have >/content/< anywhere in them. >/content/< is a directory i see in my FTP, my URL's generally are >example.com/catalog/....< or >example.com/catalog/products/...<

Comment: Then you can add that entry to your robots.txt with no fear, robots.txt only block what Google reaches, which are your URLs